# R-Package to make a figure for reclassification

Tags: r, classification, bar-chart

I would like to make a figure like the one below to show reclassified subjects.

[image]

(figure from this paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1936878X20304277)

How can I do this in R? Does anyone know a package?

Comment: [Sankey Diagram](https://r-graph-gallery.com/sankey-diagram.html). The Sankey diagram better conveys the message, and looks beautiful too.